# Regex match everything between two {}

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I was looking at different answers here but unfortunately none of them was good for my case. So I hope you don't mind about it.

So I need to match everything between two curly brackets {} except situation when match starts with @ and without these curly brackets e.g:

1. "This is a super text {**match_this**}"
2. "{**match_this**}"
3. "This is another example @{deal_with_it}"

Here are my test strings, 1,2,3 are valid while the last one shouldn't be:

```
  1   {eww}
  2   r23r23{fetwe}
  3   #{d2dded}
  4   @{d2dded}
```

I was trying with:

```
(?<=[^@]\{)[^\}]*(?=\})
```

Then only 2th and 3th options were matches (without the first one)
https://regex101.com/r/qRInUf/2/

Then I was trying:

```
\{(.*?)\} or [^@]\{(.*?)\}
```

In both cases I was unable to match 1,2,3 values
https://regex101.com/r/uYRtLD/1

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: This is for java.

Comment: This is for a java

Comment: What about `.?(?<!@)\{([^}]*)}`?

Comment: Are you trying to match the character preceding `{` or just the `{x}` part?

Comment: @ctwheels It works but in the 2 (r23r23{text}) it creates two groups. Is there a option that will create only one group?

Comment: So you just want to match what's inside `{}`?

Comment: I'm trying to match only the x part of it.

Comment: Gotcha ok so what about `(?<=(?<!@){)([^}]*)(?=})`?

Comment: you are my hero :) it works
You can answer it and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: One of your patterns would almost have worked. You just need to alternate with `^` start anchor: [`(?:^|[^@])\{([^}]*)}`](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyye8546r) or with lookbehind `(?<!@)\{([^}]*)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/uYRtLD/2)

```
(?<=(?<!@)\{)[^}]*(?=})
```

- `(?<=(?<!@)\{)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches the following

  - `(?<!@)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes doesn't match `@` literally
  - `\{` Match `{` literally.
- `[^}]*` Matches any character except `}` any number of times
- `(?=})` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `}` literally

Results:

```
{eww}           # Matches eww
r23r23{fetwe}   # Matches fetwe
#{d2dded}       # Matches d2dded
@{d2dded}       # Does not match this because @ precedes {
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex:

```
(?<!@\{)(?<=\{).*?(?=\})
```

A negative lookbehind to assure no `@{`, a positive lookbehind to assure a `{` and a positive lookahead to assure a `}`.

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/5gA4Ji/1).

Comment: `.*` will give incorrect results if two `{}` exist in the same string. See it working incorrectly [here](https://regex101.com/r/ig9rrW/2)

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks for pointing that out. Changed to `.*?`. https://regex101.com/r/5gA4Ji/1